# Is there a way to create a simple custom tile images with codename one

Tags: android, ios, storage, cross-platform, codenameone

I want to create a custom image gallery from capturing images on the device but I can not find a way to do it in Codename one, the openGallery() function is about selecting the images and not creating a custom image galley and accessing the file system not working as I needed to address the gallery images files.
Can anyone give me a suggestion or is it even possible?

Comment: You can't just change the gallery since filesystems in devices are restricted. Each app has access to its own file system. If you want to add a file to the gallery you can use the CN.share* APIs.